# how to use the "display" function in a scala 2.11 with Spark 2.0 notebook in dsx

Tags: dsx, data-science-experience, pixiedust

In dsx is there a way to use "display" in a scala 2.11 with Spark 2.0 notebook (I know it can be done in a python notebook with pixiedust). Eg:

```
display(spark.sql("SELECT COUNT(zip), SUM(pop), city FROM hive_zips_table 
                   WHERE state = 'CA' GROUP BY city ORDER BY SUM(pop) DESC"))
```

But I want to do the same in a scala notebook. Currently I am just doing a show command below that just give data in a tabular format with no graphics etc.

```
spark.sql("SELECT COUNT(zip), SUM(pop), city FROM hive_zips_table 
          WHERE state = 'CA' GROUP BY city ORDER BY SUM(pop) DESC").show()
```

Comment: @close_voters -  I have updated the question to help it satisfy the stackoverflow requirements.

Answer (score 3):

Note:

- Pixiedust currently works with Spark 1.6 and Python 2.7.
- Pixiedust currently supports Spark DataFrames, Spark GraphFrames and Pandas

Reference:-
https://github.com/ibm-cds-labs/pixiedust/wiki

But if you can use Spark 1.6 ,here is a quick way around to use that fancy display function:-

You can go the other way around, Since Pixidust let you use scala and python in one python notebook with %%scala line magic.

https://github.com/ibm-cds-labs/pixiedust/wiki/Using-Scala-language-within-a-Python-Notebook

**Step 1.** Create a notebook with python 2 and spark 1.6
Install pixidust and import it

```
!pip install --user --no-deps --upgrade pixiedust
import pixiedust
```

Define your variables or your dataframe in Scala under

```
%%scala
import org.apache.spark.sql._

print(sc.version)

val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
val __df = sqlContext.read.json("people.json")

__df.show()
```

or

do whatever to create your dataframe

```
val __df = dataframe1.sql("SELECT COUNT(zip), SUM(pop), city FROM hive_zips_table 
      WHERE state = 'CA' GROUP BY city ORDER BY SUM(pop) DESC").show()
```

**Step 2:** In separate cell run following to access df variable in your python shell.

```
display(__df)
```

Reference to my sample Notebook:-

- IBM Notebook: https://apsportal.ibm.com/analytics/notebooks/095520cb-c9ff-4f4a-a829-f458f20b4505/view?access_token=d4de7944ad7d6bfc179632a3036a7971c130e54d1a30ecf5df34ece8c4f8c3b5
- Github: https://github.com/charles2588/bluemixsparknotebooks/blob/master/pixiedust/PixiedustTestCase.ipynb

Thanks,
Charles.

Comment: Should @Vik M raise a uservoice ticket or a github issue to request support for spark 2.0 and scala 2.11?

Comment: Raise github issue since it will get direct attention of pixiedust devs.
I am sure spark 2 implementation should be on its way.

Comment: @Vik M I think you can accept Charles' answer and raise a new issue on github?

Comment: Could you please include the necessary import(s)?
import org.apache.spark.sql._ does not seem to suffice.

Comment: @ChristianNeverdal are you running into error? Which other import you are referring to?

Answer (score 1):

You can get similar result in Zeppelin

```
z.show(dataframe)
```